# executing a command via php on raspberry pi

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell, raspberry-pi

I try to load this php file (bluetoothModul.php):

```
<?php
 exec("echo '1' > /dev/rfcomm0");
?>
```

with this html file:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="bluetoothModul.php"><img src="test.png"</a>
</body>
</html>
```

on my raspberry pi apache2 server but nothing happens.

If I execute the php file via command line: php bluetoothModul.php it is working correctly.

Maybe there is something wrong with the permissions?

[image: permission]

Comment: Does the webserver running your PHP script, have access to echo things to `/dev/rfcomm0`? *(Pro tip: Include what your `/var/log/<webserver>/error.log` says)*

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: I just told you, check the error log. Or if that's empty, check `dmsg` or `journalctl`. Start by debugging before you ask questions, because we need this information and so do you. And maybe you'll figure something out while checking these basic things. Sorry for being blunt, but asking questions before checking logs is, well it's odd. But yes, this is most likely a permission problem, as you assumed yourself.

Comment: you're right sorry for that. In the log I get this: sh: 1: cannot create /dev/rfcomm0: Permission denied

Comment: There you go, now you do `ls -l /dev | grep rfcomm0` and do `ps aux | grep <webserver>` and check whether or not the user running the webserver have permissions on the object you're trying to write to. Most objects under `/dev` is owned by root, tty, disk or audio/video. Rarely does anything in `/dev` permission by `www-data`/`http`.

Comment: rfcomm0 is owned by root and apache2 by www-data